# Preferred Way to Write Domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose a complex function is defined everywhere on the complex plane except for at 0 and the negative integers. Is this the preferred way to write the domain?

$$\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$$

I'm not sure how common that is or if there's a more typical way it would be written. Maybe

$$\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,-1,...\}$$

is clearer? Or perhaps something else? Thoughts?

Comment: like the gamma function?  I think your notations are fine

Comment: I've seen and am used to $$\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_0^-,$$ but believe it's not widely used. I think your first suggestion is the most succinct and clear.

Comment: The 2nd way is not clearer because "$,...$"  is often open to interpretation. You could use $\Bbb C \setminus \{n\in \Bbb Z : n\le 0\}.$ But your 1st way is fine for me.